# PHP Code always tells me that the directory isn't empty

Tags: php

The code below needs to read the directory uploads/ but he always tells me that the directory is not empty, even when it totally *is* empty.

```
<?php
  $dir = "uploads/";
  echo (count(glob("$dir/*")) === 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
?>
```

Is there a error in this code or anything or am I just going crazy?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php
  echo (count(glob("uploads/*")) === 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
?>
```

**FULL PAGE CODE UPDATE**

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('error', $_GET)) {
    echo '<div class="galleryError">That image could not be found, we&#39;re sorry!</div>';
} elseif (array_key_exists('unknownerror', $_GET)) {
    echo '<div class="galleryError">There went something wrong</div>';
} else {
    echo '';
}

if ($handle = opendir('uploads/')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo "<div class='imgbox'><a href='fullscreen.php?token=$entry'><img src='$submap$gallery$entry' class='boximg'></a><p class='boxname'>$entry<br /><a href='?view&token=$entry'><small>View this image</small></a></p></div>";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

// all the above is working but then we have this lonely code over here which refuses to work.

```
echo (count(glob("uploads/*")) == 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
?>
```

Comment: Just simple replace `$dir` in your glob statement and you will see it! -> `glob("uploads//*")`

Comment: What happens when you take out the count stuff and just look at the result of the glob?

Comment: @Rizier123 It still tells me that the directory is "not empty"

Comment: @stacker Did you checked if you have files in it? Also is the path correct?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, there are really no files in that directory. I've also tried what Wooble said, but it still tells me that there are files in that directory while there aren't..

Comment: @stacker Works fine for me! See no error. (Maybe restart whatever isn't working, or open the folder new and check if there are files in it (Maybe hidden files))

Comment: Or do this: `$files = glob("uploads/*"); print_r($files);` And you see which files are in the dir

Comment: @Rizier123 Nop, sadly that also doesn't work. There must be a error or something on my page. I'm going to post the full code.

Comment: @Rizier123 Full code posted

Comment: @stacker Just simply try the code as own script and if it still doesn't work i have no idea

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happened when you printed the result of the glob? It should tell you what is in the directory. My guess is you're making a wrong assumption about what directory it is. Try an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

`glob` is silently failing.  I couldn't tell you why, with file system access **it's usually permissions related** but there could be other factors - it even says in the documentation that the functionality is partially dependent on your server environment...

> On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.

When there's a `glob` error it returns `false` - and `count(false) === 1` (also documented) so it's no surprise folks get into confusing situations when they ignore these checks.  If you really don't care about errors you can utilise the short-hand ternary operator to make an inline false-check, ensuring an array is always passed to `count` so it will behave as expected:

```php
$isEmpty = count(glob("uploads/*")?:[]) === 0;
```

This still doesn't get around the fact that the directory is not being read though - have you tried printing the output of glob when you **do** have files in the directory?  I'd imagine that's borked too.  What does the following print? :

```php
var_dump(is_readable('./uploads'));
```

Does the output of the following match your *expected* working directory? :

```php
echo realpath('uploads');
```

*FYI* use `var_dump` when debugging, not `print_r` as suggested in the comments - it will give you more detail about the variables / types / structures / references etc. that you actually need.

---

*In summary - things to consider:*

What *OS* is running on the server? What mode is *PHP* running in? Is it running under SuPHP / FastCGI or similar context.  What user owns the `./uploads` directory, what permissions are set on it?